# Netlogo: Help in understanding this dialog box

Tags: netlogo

I have been working with a Netlogo model with apparently no problem, but I have just tried to open it and this message appeared:

[image]

The blurred text is only the file path. Any help to open the file would be greatly appreciated.

Javier

Comment: Hey Javier, that sounds like [this bug](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1629).  The short answer is to not use double-quotes in plot pen names.  You can open your nlogo file in a text editor and find any plot pen names with double quotes, remove the double-quotes, save (as a different file name, just in case), and try to re-open.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, it was a double-quote bug. The problem was: ........"By "new"" 1.0 0 -7500403 true "" "plot count patches with [atractor-state = \"new\"]" ........and was fixed with:....... "By new" 1.0 0 -7500403 true "" "plot count patches with [atractor-state = \"new\"]"